# How to deal with two TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have two instances of UITableView in one app, and the problem is that I don't know how to define what each table needs to display. Here's the code:

.h :

```
{
NSArray *array1;
NSArray *array2;
IBOutlet UITableView *table1;
IBOutlet UITableView *table2;
}
```

.m :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array1 count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

This code is working for just one table. I don't know how to set up the other table with array2. Have you got any ideas, people?

Comment: All the delegated methods you listed have the tableView parameter.  You can do a comparison to see if tableView is table1 or table2 then act accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is check which `UITableView` you are setting up in the `delegate/datasource` methods. Try:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView; {
  if(tableView == table1){
    return 1; // The number of sections in table1;
  }
else if(tableView == table2){
    return 1; // The number of sections in table2;
  }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section; {
  if(tableView == table1){
    return [array1 count];
  }
  else if(tableView == table2){
    return [array2 count];
  }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if(cell == nil){
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }
  if(tableView == table1){
    cell.textLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];;
  }
  else if(tableView == table2){
    cell.textLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];;
  }
  return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
  UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: You cannot compare objects like this in objective-c. You have to use isEqual:(id) method. Comparing like this will be comparing the address of each pointer.

Comment: The method `isEqual:(id)` does in fact check the object to see if it is equal to another object, whereas `==` just compares the pointers of two objects. In this case, however, the `IBOutlet UITablveView * table1` holds a reference to the pointer of the the `UITableView`, so in this instance, checking the pointers is not only valid, but also faster!

Answer (score 2):

On UITableViewDataSource methods you have to compare your ivars with the delegates.

like this:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if([tableView isEqual:table1])
    {
          return [array1 count];
    }
    else if([tableView isEqual:table2])
    {
          return [array2 count];
    }
    else
    {
          return 0;
    }
}
```

Do this for every method in the callback.

But I would recommend having only one tableView and load different contents in it based on some flag. You would have to call `[tableView reloadData]` in order for this to function and set a flag. Then you would change the above code like this `if([flag isEqualToString:@"table1"]) { //code for table1 }`

Unless you have two tables on the same View. Then the first method is what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to create separate datasource/delegate objects for each table view.  They don't have to be separate classes.  They can be two instances of the same class.