# How to use didSelctRowAtIndexPath in multipletableview in iOS?

Tags: ios

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text); 
}
```

but in case of multiple tableview i can't get select table cell
for table 1:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
{  
   if(tableview==table1)   
       NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text);
   }
   if(tableview==table2)
   {
       NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text);
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with two TableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318098/how-to-deal-with-two-tableview)

Comment: And from where does come from the var `cell`?

Answer (score 2):

When you add your uitableview in storyboard define unique tag number to specify the table. let's say the first tableview have tag 1 and the second have tag 2:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
{  
   if(tableView.tag==1)   
       NSLog(@"tableView 1");
   }else{
       NSLog(@"tableView 2");
   }
}
```